# Check a range of pages and extract the <h1> content if the page exists using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, get

There is a website like:

```
www.example.com/index.aspx?id=1
```

The `id` value is not ordered, maybe like `1`, `32`, `68`, `61321`, ...

How can I find out which pages exist and extract the content of the `<h1>` with jQuery?

I used following code in a loop, but no luck.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    var URL = 'http://www.example.com/index.aspx?id=' + i.toString();
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (res) {
            var h = $(res.responseText).find('h1').text();
            alert(h);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: well, you should check the status, if it is `200` the page exist

Comment: the problem is that there is no 200 error page for not-exist pages, they exist with a custom text

Comment: _"extract the **`<h1>`** value if the page exists"_ _".find('**h**')"_?

Comment: well 200 is the status code for an exiting page, anw...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.when.apply($, 
    $.map(Array(1001), function(_, key) {
        return $.get("http://www.example.com/index.aspx?id=" 
               + (key + 1)
               , function(res, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                     var h = $(jqxhr.responseText).find("h1").text();
                     alert(h);
               })
    })
);
```

Comment: I don’t see how a HEAD request is supposed to help here.